# Getting a cross-thread invalid operation on different control when changing form background color

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am changing the winforms back color when a database connection is lost. I am doing this through a delegate:

```
    private void SetOfflineBackColor(Color color)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetOfflineBackground d = SetOfflineBackColor;

            Invoke(d,BackColor = color );
        }
        else
        {

            BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
        }
    }
```

and it works fine. However, there is another control, a textbox, which is now throwing a cross-thread error when I make the invoke call. I can't figure out why this textbox is even being included in the invoke.
Is there a way to dive in and see why, or am I just missing something in my call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern, which is much more readable:

```
private void SetOfflineBackColor(Color color)
{
    // if method is called from another thread, it will be enqued to the dispatcher
    if (InvokeRequired) {
        Action<Color> action = SetOfflineBackground;
        Invoke(action, color);
        return;
    }

    // now you can continue as usual
    BackColor = color;
}
```

The problem in your code is in `Invoke(d,BackColor = color );`.
It's equivalent cod for:

```
var rslt = BackColor = color;
Invoke(d, rslt);
```

And the problem is the assignement into `BackColor` property is still in the non-UI thread.

Comment: This one worked but I couldn't use SetOfflineBackground directly in the call, i had to create the delegate variable. Just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an assignment in your invoke call.  Try changing

```
Invoke(d,BackColor = color );
```

to

```
Invoke(d, color );
```

or

```
Invoke(new Action(() => BackColor = color));
```

since you ignore the color parameter when no invoke is required.

Comment: I tried this and the back color does not change at all.